# DirectConnection cannot be used when ConnectionModeSwitch is set to UseConnectionMode while connect with Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to connect with Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB via ASP.NET app. To start I use connection string provided by Microsoft (when creating an instance by Azure)

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://[myInstanceName]:
[primaryAccountKey]@[myInstanceName].documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&retrywrites=false&replicaSet=globaldb
&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@mongocosmocoffedb@");

var database = client.GetDatabase("productdb");

var collection = database.GetCollection<Product>("productcollection");
return Ok(collection);
```

But when I use this connection string I got error

```
DirectConnection cannot be used when ConnectionModeSwitch is set to UseConnectionMode.
```

I found [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000623/what-is-the-mongodb-connection-string-on-a-azure-cosmos-db-provisioned-with-a-gr) and try use

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://[myInstanceName]:
[primaryAccountKey]@[myInstanceName].documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true");
```

but in this case i got error

```
MaxWireVersion is not known.
```

Comment: regarding `directConnection`, are you sure that you don't configure any other option for client? via connectionString or MongoClientSettings? What's in stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

This is the connection mode port issue. The port number you mentioned 10255 is used for geo-replication and that is causing the issue. Post numbers 10255, 10256 map to the instance that has geo-replication.

Change the port number to 10255. 10250 maps to the default Azure cosmos DB API for Mongo DB. In case of using geo-replication, public end point you can use 10255

Refer the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-sdk-connection-modes